# Python. Learning turtle graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I want to draw this picture using turtle.

This is what I got atm:

```
import turtle


    def animal():
        turtle.speed(1)
        turtle.pencolor('black')
        turtle.up()
        turtle.goto(-180, -180)
        turtle.down()
        turtle.lt(180)
        turtle.circle(-200, 180)
        turtle.lt(90)
        turtle.circle(50, 220)
        turtle.done()
```

So the question is how to draw mouse ears after drawing body semicircle. Because in my code mouse ears intersect with body. Is it any good way to do it without guessing correct coordinates and after return to the point where was ear started?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any good way to do it without guessing correct coordinates and after
>   return to the point where was ear started

This code should do both things that you request: 1) draw the ear without having to know where to stop; 2) return to where the ear started drawing:

```
import turtle

def animal():
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(-180, 180)
    turtle.lt(90)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.fillcolor('gray45')
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(75)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.lt(90)
    turtle.fillcolor('white')
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(170, 180)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.circle(170, -180)

animal()

turtle.done()
```

[image]